# Issue in DB pooling using cx_oracle and Flask (Python)

Tags: oracle, kubernetes, gunicorn, cx-oracle, flask-restful

We have develoed an APP using Angular 8 and flask-restplus(0.13.0) (Python 3.7.4) and cx_oracle(7.2.3).
The Angular app is deployed on NGINX on Ubuntu server. We have created 3 micro services and have deployed it on gunicorn using docker and kubernetes pods.
Production environment is having 7 kubernetes PODs per service. 
In Yaml file of kubernetes we have configured it to run on 4 threads using below command.

```
["gunicorn"]
  args: ["run_app:app","-b","0.0.0.0:8080","--threads=4","--access-logfile","-","--error-logfile","-"]
```

The session pool code  is as follows:

```
dbsession_pool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool('xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx.xxxxx.com/xxxxxdb', min=5, max=50, increment=5, threaded = True)
```

All the services run for a while and then start giving 504 gateway timeout error after some time.
But if we use cx_Oracle.connect then it works fine. Our reason to use session pool was to save time for connecting and disconnecting to DB thus improving performance.

Comment: Check to see if your connections are being returned to the pool.  If you use the "with pool.acquire() as connection:" code fragment, that will ensure that happens. If you retain the connection anywhere it will not get closed -- unless you explicitly do so, of course!

Comment: After the deployment if we check the session pool at oracle db using
`select * from v$session where username='DATABASE'`
The count is around 4000. The application works for few time.
 After some time the active session count starts decline and becomes zero.
 Due to this the Python services starts throwing 504 error as db connection is lost.It starts working again if we redeploy the code.

Comment: We have also tried using session pool using sqlalchemy  
`from sqlalchemy import create_engine
db =create_engine('oracle://xxxxdb:xxxxdb@xxxxdb.xxxxxxx.com/xxxxdb',coerce_to_decimal=False,echo=True,echo_pool=True,pool_size=1,max_overflow=0,pool_timeout=5,pool_pre_ping=True)
`But the result is same.

Comment: Ditto! Getting into same issue, @OnkarKubal  how did you solve it?